# Ignore DOM typings in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 (truly VSCodium) and TypeScript 4.0.3. Given a large project for NodeJS and this `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "typeRoots": ["*.d.ts"]
}
```

I'm still getting suggestions for the DOM (web browser API) from `lib.dom.d.ts` in the application package itself:

`/Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`

I tried setting `noLib: false` but `tsc` complains that conflicts with the `lib` option.
How can I ensure VSCode does the right thing? Am I missing something? When trying to do a repro on a small project, it seemingly works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed it down to using `@types/supertest` which depends on `@types/superagent`. In their type definitions they are importing the DOM API. There exists a current issue on GitHub: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41425

Answer (score 1):

Exclude node_modules from `tsconfig.json` so it stops complaining about external packages:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "typeRoots": ["*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: theres no complaints about the `node_modules`